# Perl HTTP Tiny + Socket Socks Wrapper Timeout not working

Tags: perl, sockets, http, timeout, socks

I am using [HTTP::Tiny](http://search.cpan.org/~dagolden/HTTP-Tiny-0.038/lib/HTTP/Tiny.pm) + [IO::Socket::Socks::Wrapper](http://search.cpan.org/~oleg/IO-Socket-Socks-Wrapper-0.08/lib/IO/Socket/Socks/Wrapper.pm) to send a HTTP Request over a SOCKS Proxy. Everything is working fine except the timeout option.
When using only IO::Socket::Socks without HTTP::Tiny the timeout is working.

Example without HTTP::Tiny and a non existent proxy to trigger a timeout:

```
my $t = time;
my $sock = IO::Socket::Socks->new(
    ProxyAddr => '4.5.6.7', 
    ProxyPort => 1080, 
    ConnectAddr => 'www.google.com', 
    ConnectPort => 80, 
    Timeout => 3
) or print "connection failed or timed out\n";

print "time: " . (time - $t) . "\n";
```

Output:

```
connection failed or timed out
time: 3.00517201423645
```

Example with HTTP::Tiny:

```
my $t = time;
my $http = wrap_connection(
    HTTP::Tiny->new(timeout => 3), {
        ProxyAddr => '4.5.6.7', 
        ProxyPort => 1080, 
        Timeout => 3
    }
);
my $r = $http->get("http://www.google.com");
print "connection failed or timed out\n" unless $r->{success};
print "time: " . (time - $t) . "\n";
```

Output:

```
connection failed or timed out
time: 21.0282030105591
```

Why does the second example not timeout after 3 seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was bug, which now seems to be fixed. New version will be uploaded to CPAN soon.
And right now you can get fixed version from github repo.